# Как получить __name__ от композитного типа в питоне?

Tags: python, типы

Я пишу библиотеку которая создает файлы с классами динамично. Работаю много с типами. Переодически нужно имя типа в виде строки.

```
int_type_as_string = int.__name__ # int_type_as_string == 'int'
```

Композитный тип выдает ошибку при аналогичном коде

```
from typing import List

list_of_int_type_as_string = List[str].__name__
```

Результирует в AttributeError: __ name__

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    list_of_int_type_as_string = List[str].__name__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: __name__
```

Как получить тот же эффект от композитного типа, как List[str]?
В переменную нужно сохранить строку 'List[str]'. str и repr не работают:

```
str(List[str]) == 'typing.List[str]'
repr(List[str]) == 'typing.List[str]'
```

Comment: А чем вам `typing.List[str]` не угодил? Это значение, как минимум, логичное

Comment: а почему бы просто не отсечь тогда `typing` из полученной строки `str` / `repr`?

Comment: Да, вероятно оба варианта имеют право на жизнь. Я просто думал, что в питоне уже есть встроенный функционал решит мне проблему

Comment: @BitBeats Встроенный функционал - это `str`, он как-раз всё правильно показывает. Для встроенных типов - только имя типа, а для типов из подключаемых библиотек - имя вместе с библиотекой. Всё же логично. А то мало ли откуда ещё этот тип подключен.

Answer (score 3):

Ну напишите простую функцию, которая будет приспосабливаться под нужные вам варианты:

```
from typing import List, Union

def get_class_name(cls):
    return getattr(cls, '__name__', str(cls).replace('typing.',''))

print(get_class_name(int))
print(get_class_name(List[str]))
print(get_class_name(List[dict]))
print(get_class_name(List[Union[dict, str]]))
```

Вывод:

```
int
List[str]
List[dict]
List[Union[dict, str]]
```

Comment: get_class_name(List[dict]) не возвращает пустую строку

Comment: Более сложные классы тоже не очень работают. get_class_name(List[Union[dict, str]]) возвращает List[typing.Union[dict, str]]

Comment: Не знаю, у меня `List[dict]` нормально работает. Сделал другой вариант, чтобы все `typing.` убирались. Так то я вам в принципе пример что можно сделать показал, а не прямо готовое решение.

Comment: Сторонние модули вида `thirdparty.sometyping` не очень рады такому решению

Comment: @andreymal В любом случае это какой-то костыль. Непонятно, зачем это всё по большому счёту нужно.